# No return value from function in Python 3? Why do I have to do a = int(a, 16) in Python instead of just int(a)

Tags: python, function

Let's say I have the following function that gets called in Python 3

```
def receive(dat, rowIndex, message, bytes):
    bytes = binascii.hexlify(bytes)
    print(bytes)
```

Why do I have to put `bytes = binascii.hexlify(bytes)` instead of just:

```
def receive(dat, rowIndex, message, bytes):
    binascii.hexlify(bytes)
    print(bytes)
```

and that would `hexlify` the `bytes` variable.  If nothing is returned by that function, isn't the value of `bytes` changed?

Comment: No, because that's not what `hexlify` is documented to do.  (And it's not documented to do it because it can't, since strings are immutable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bytes` type is immutable, you cannot change the value. `binascii.hexlify()` is a function that takes bytes, and returns a string. It cannot modify the bytes. Something is returned by the function, it is just that you are not doing anything with the return value. `hexlify()` "Return[s] the hexadecimal representation of the binary data. Every byte of data is converted into the corresponding 2-digit hex representation. The resulting string is therefore twice as long as the length of data."

When you write

```
x = binascii.hexlify(b)
```

then `binascii.hexlify()` returns a string that is stored in `x`.

When you write

```
binascii.hexlify(b)
```

then the exact same string is returned, but is discarded as you do not store it anywhere.

Also, `bytes` is a built-in type. It is considered bad style to use the names of built-in functions, types etc as variable names because that quickly becomes confusing. What if you need to use the built-in `bytes()` later in your function?

Comment: Just to enhance your answer, according to [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html), hexlify does: `Return the hexadecimal representation of the binary data. Every byte of data is converted into the corresponding 2-digit hex representation. The resulting string is therefore twice as long as the length of data.`

Comment: Thanks @kecer, incorporated that.

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html):

> binascii.hexlify(data) Return the hexadecimal representation of the
>   binary data. Every byte of data is converted into the corresponding
>   2-digit hex representation. The resulting string is therefore twice as
>   long as the length of data.

`hexlify` therefore does not change the `bytes` object received, but returns a string. Thats why you need the `bytes =` part.